# How can I ignore specific files when I am parsing a directory?

Tags: python, os.walk

I am trying to parse this directory and I want to see all the txt files except for three specific names.
With the code I have wrote I can get all of the text files in all of the directories.

```
for root,dirnames,filenames in os.walk('D:/datast12'):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.txt'):
        matches.append([root,filenames])
```

Do anyone knows how can I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
files_to_ignore = ('abc.txt', 'foo.txt', 'bar.txt')

for root,dirnames,filenames in os.walk('D:/datast12'):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.txt'):
        if filename in files_to_ignore: continue
        matches.append([root,filenames])
```

Comment: or simply : `if filename not in files_to_ignore: matches.append([root,filenames])`

Comment: or even simpler, if `matches` was supposed to be empty at the start: `matches = [[root, filenames] for root,dirnames,filenames in os.walk('D:/datast12') for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.txt') if filename not in files_to_ignore]`

Comment: and, the faster `files_to_ignore` grows, the more important: if it is a `set()`, the `in`/`not in` operation works faster.

Comment: `os.walk()`, even if suggested by original poster, is (in the best case) not the optimum routine, since it searches the whole subtree, if there is one. This can easily be seen by the fact, that it returns values never used. Replacing it by `os.listdir()` should be fine.